# I can't figure out how to make my animation work in my blender game

Tags: animation, game-engine

I can't figure out how to make my animation work in my blender game. Can I get some help? Can someone just see if you can get the animation to work in the blender game and post it back up here? I want to make the hit action to work with the left mouse click and I need help with making the camera, character and knife/action to work all together in blender game?
 Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please add some information to your question as to what you are attempting and at what point it is going wrong.

Comment: how do i add file?

Comment: You can use this site and embed the code it gives you into your question: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The download is now there